# General formula for nth element of the sequence 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Give a general formula for nth element of the sequence 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, ...

I have been trying any combination, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $a_n =1-\frac{1}{3}\left(1+e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}n}+e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}n}\right)$ works.

Comment: I think that works too; $+1$

Comment: @Jet Chung trying it on excel but it gives me an error

=1-(1/3)*(1 + EXP(((COMPLEX(0,2)*PI())*J8/3)*J8)+EXP(((COMPLEX(0,4)*PI())*J8/3)*J8))

I'm probably writing the formula incorrectly

Comment: I'll mark your correct if the answer is more accurate

Comment: @Luther I don't really know how to use Excel, but a quick Google search tells me COMPLEX(COS(2*PI()*J8/3), SIN(2*PI()*J8/3)) and COMPLEX(COS(4*PI()*J8/3), SIN(4*PI()*J8/3)) should work.

Comment: Where I'm using $e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta} + i \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: This seems to work in Google sheets (I assume it would work the same in Excel): =COMPLEX(ROUND(2/3-(COS(2*PI()/3*A1)+COS(4*PI()/3*A1))/3, 5), ROUND((SIN(2*PI()/3*A1)+SIN(4*PI()/3*A1))/3,5))

Answer (score 2):

How about $a_n=\dfrac43\sin^2\left(\dfrac{n\pi}3\right)$?

Comment: using this formula in excel =(4/3)*POWER(SIN((n*PI())/3),2) but i get a wrong answer

Comment: when I use that formula in Excel, it looks right

Comment: @Luther Double-check the values of $n$.

Comment: yep all good thanks

Comment: I realized that we needed something with period $3$; that suggested sin or cos of multiples of   $\frac\pi3$; if squared, $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}3\right)$ gives $0$ when $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $\frac34$ otherwise, so I scaled by $\frac43$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is divisible by $3$, then $a_n=0$. Otherwise, $a_n=1$.

So, the formula $a_n=\min(n \bmod 3,1)$ should work.